# How to allow set of special characters in existing regex?

Tags: java, javascript, regex, pattern-matching

We have regex to validate password with one digit, one upper case letter and one lower case letter. Regex is:

```
^\w*(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[a-z])(?=\w*[A-Z])\w*$
```

This regex will not allow any special characters. I need to change regex to allow some list of special characters and there should not be any restriction that there must be at least one special character. Only `` [-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/] `` should be allowed as special characters without must have one restriction.

I tried:

```
^\w*(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[a-z])(?=\w*[A-Z])(?=\w*[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]*)\w*$
```

and which seems to be wrong. Please some one help.

Comment: The `]` char is a special character inside the `[]`, you should scape some characteres inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of `\w*` before `$`.You are specifically trying to match 0 to many words..Try this:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[-\w!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]+$
```

OR

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[\w\p{Punct}]+$
```

`\p{Punct}` is a special character class similar to `[!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_{|}~]`

Comment: He wanted punctuation to be allowed, but not required. You may remove the 4th look-ahead. (:

Comment: Lone Nebula, Anirudh: Thank you so much for this help.

Comment: This still doesn't work.  Password123&&& works but Password&&&123 does not work.